# How can I set all mail to read from yahoo instant messenger / reset notification?

Tags: yahoo-messenger

Yahoo! Instant Messenger notifies of new emails, it shows the email subject in a popup, and an icon appears to show that there is new/unread email.

Suppose I want to reset the notification or set those emails to "read" without the elongated process of going into Yahoo! email to do it?  Yes, Yahoo! Instant Messenger makes that manual process of going into Yahoo! Mail a bit faster, but I'd still prefer to reset that notification icon without doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
C:\getmail>getmail
GetMail v1.33: WinNT console utility to download a mailbox's mail.
```

A command line email client running in the background, just download one email or better, one email header..

if you retrieve even the first email (The oldest), then yahoo messenger email notification thing resets.

getmail -u user -pw pswd -s pop.mail.yahoo.co.uk -headersonly -n 1

put it in a bat file, drag that to quick launch, tell it cmd /c blah.bat  and run minimized.

So when you get an email notification popup, you just click that, and it fairly quietly does what it needs, and quickly, and resets the notification.  It may not work when you're logged in, in yahoo's case at least.

It doesn't set all mail to read, maybe it would if you got them all, but I am not looking to do that.. i'm just looking to reset the notification.

I have done it now so it retrieves the most recent 10 emails so sets them read, naturally also, removing the notification. I did it by calling getmail twice, once to get the total number of messages, and again to get msgs from the point totalmsg minus 10.